# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: only returning one custom uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have been through my debugger and noticed my code will only return one customcell from my 
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.. I don't know why or how to make it return both the customcells I want it to.. all it dose is display the same custom cell in both sections.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger rows = 0;
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            rows = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            rows = 1;
            break;
    }
    return rows;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        //Registration Button
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomRegCell";
        static NSString *CellNib = @"LogInCustomCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

    //Registration Button
    static NSString *CellButtonIdentifier = @"CustomSubmitCell";
    static NSString *CellButtonNib = @"LogInCustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cellButton = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellButtonIdentifier];
    if (cellButton == nil) {
        NSArray *nibButton = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellButtonNib owner:self options:nil];
        cellButton = (UITableViewCell *)[nibButton objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.section);
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            return cell;    // jumps out of method here     

    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        return cellButton;          

    }
    return nil; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            if(indexPath.section==0)
       {............
          return cell;
         }
          else if(indexpath.section==1)
      {
          .....
         return cellbutton;
       }
}
```

Comment: Okay, Heres my answer after testing an idea I had..

Basically My code is correct, my error has something to do with trying to call two custom cells from the same .nib file. I have since made a new .nib for my custom submit button and it loads into that second field perfectly.

So it was something I had done with the setup in interface builder, has anyone else come across this before?